# Disabling virtual terminal while grabbing /dev/input/event*

Tags: raspbian, tty, keyboard-event

On an embedded system (running Raspbian Stretch without X) I have a C++ application that sometimes "grabs" the raw keyboard inputs from /dev/input/event*.

When this happens (I set a flag in my code, so I know when) I want to disable the current virtual terminal (tty). This is to avoid to send commands to the o.s. when the user types.

Please note I don't want to disable the tty entirely! I just want to unbind the keyboard input from it.

Comment: Dealt with at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173712/ .

Comment: Thanks, in the link is explicitly written that the best way is to use ioctl, setting the flag KDSKBMUTE. I'm not able to find which header define that and which fd I should use (i.e. to find the current tty).